# Bootstrap collapsible navbar open on start

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with a bootstrap navbar. In the mobile view the navbar should open on click, but it is open already, when the page is loaded.

I guess it is just a simple mistake, but I just cannot find it.

If somebody knows, please tell me! :-)

Philip

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container container-navigation">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-9">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#fws-navbar" aria-controls="fws-navbar" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <!-- text logo on mobile view -->
          <a class="navbar-brand visible-xs" href="index.htm">Fahrrad-Workshop Sprockhövel</a>
        </div>
        <div id="fws-navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

            <li class="nav-dropdown">
              <a href="mountainbike-workshop.htm" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> Mountainbike <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="mountainbike-workshop.htm">Übersicht MTB-Workshop</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="schaltung-umwerfer-workshop.htm">Schaltung und Umwerfer</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="ketten-kassetten-workshop.htm">Kette und Kassette</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="scheibenbremsen-workshop-fahrraeder.htm">Felgen-/Scheibenbremsen</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="innenlager-workshop-fahrraeder.htm">Innenlager und Kurbel</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="fahrrad-naben-workshop.htm">Laufräder und Naben</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="steuerkopf-workshop.htm">Gabel und Steuerkopf</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="fahrwerk-abstimmen-workshop.htm">Federgabel und Dämpfer</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="innenzuege-aussenhuellen-workshop.htm">Züge und Außenhüllen</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="handgriffe.htm">Lenker und Griffe</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="klickpedal-workshop.htm">Klickpedale</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-dropdown">
              <a href="rennrad-workshop.htm" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> Rennrad <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="rennrad-workshop.htm">Übersicht Rennrad-Workshop</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="schaltung-umwerfer-workshop.htm">Schaltung und Umwerfer</a>
                </li>

                <li><a href="ketten-kassetten-workshop.htm">Kette und Kassette</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="scheibenbremsen-workshop-fahrraeder.htm">Felgenbremsen</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="innenlager-workshop-fahrraeder.htm">Innenlager und Kurbel</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="fahrrad-naben-workshop.htm">Laufräder und Naben</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="steuerkopf-workshop.htm">Gabel und Steuerkopf</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="fahrwerk-abstimmen-workshop.htm">Federgabel und Dämpfer</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="innenzuege-aussenhuellen-workshop.htm">Züge und Außenhüllen</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="handgriffe.htm">Lenker und Griffe</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="klickpedal-workshop.htm">Klickpedale</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-dropdown">
              <a href="trekkingrad-workshop.htm" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> Trekkingrad <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="trekkingrad-workshop.htm">Übersicht Trekkingrad-Workshop</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="schaltung-umwerfer-workshop.htm">Schaltung und Umwerfer</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="ketten-kassetten-workshop.htm">Kette und Kassette</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="scheibenbremsen-workshop-fahrraeder.htm">Felgenbremsen</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="innenlager-workshop-fahrraeder.htm">Innenlager und Kurbel</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="fahrrad-naben-workshop.htm">Laufräder und Naben</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="steuerkopf-workshop.htm">Gabel und Steuerkopf</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="fahrwerk-abstimmen-workshop.htm">Federgabel und Dämpfer</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="innenzuege-aussenhuellen-workshop.htm">Züge und Außenhüllen</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="handgriffe.htm">Lenker und Griffe</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-dropdown">
              <a href="elektrobike_workshop.htm" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> E-Bike <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="elektrobike_workshop.htm">Übersicht E-Bike-Workshop</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="elektro-antrieb-einbauen-fahrrad.html">Vorderrad-Antrieb einbauen</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="Elektro-Hinterrad-Antrieb-Einbauen.htm">Hinterrad-Antrieb einbauen</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="Vergleich-Laufeigenschaften-Hinterradanrieb.htm">Vergleich-Hinterradantrieb</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="Pflegen_elktrofahrrad.htm">Elektro-Antrieb-Pflege</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="Akku_workshop.htm">Workshop-Akku</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="akku-schutzhuelle.htm">Schutzhülle</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="gaint-e1-umbau-28zoll.htm">Umbau Hinterrad 28 Zoll</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-dropdown">
              <a href="tipps.htm" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <i class="fa fa-bicycle fa-fw"></i> Tipps <span class="caret"></span>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="tipps.htm">Übersicht Tipps</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="fahrrad-putzen-pflegen-workshop.htm">Putzen, Pflegen und Warten</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="ergonomie-radfahren.htm">Ergonomie: richtige Sitzposition</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="schraubenanzug.htm">Schrauben richtig anziehen</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="montage_carbon_teile.htm">Carbonteile montieren</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="schlauch_flicken.htm">Platten beheben</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Suche -->
      <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-3 suche">
        <form action="">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-search" placeholder="Suche" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default no-border-left" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                            </span>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just curious, what does aria-controls do?? I've been comparing  your code with bootstrap sample and I don't see it there.  Bootstrap - <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">   Your code- <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#fws-navbar" aria-controls="fws-navbar" aria-expanded="false">

Comment: Unable to repro

Comment: @jmag Aria-controls identifies the element whose contents or presence are controlled by the current element.

Comment: @ZimSystem How do you mean that?

Comment: It means that the problem that you describe in your question is not present in the example code you posted. The problem isn't **reproduced**.